# Having trouble getting a cumulative saving measure for a plot in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi

[image]

As the title says, I can't sum [savings] cumulatively. My total savings measure only plots monthly saving not cumulative. Any help with the Dax for the measure would be greatly appreciated, I've tried a lot of solutions online to no avail.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Power BI has a Quick Measure "Running Total" that is provided for exactly this purpose. Make sure you have a separate **Date** table and use that in the `Field` section.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the reply. It works for up to a year at a time depending on the measure of date I use. Would you know how to do it for all dates across years? For now I found the waterfall chart which is the right idea but I would like to find a way to get it as a line graph.